# Error 404: Phonegap Developer error on ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap

I'm new to phonegap, I'm trying to connect my actual app to device. When I tried to login, my ajax returns to 404 status. But when I tried it on the browser it appears to work well. I googled and tried other recommendation like whitelisting and includes meta content as well as downloading a platform but it doesn't work.

Here's my code.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Login Page</title>
   <meta charset="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
   <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
   <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
   <script src="js/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <style>
    #imglogo {
        width:  70%;
        margin: 16%;
    }
    #forms{
        padding: 5%;
    }
    html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
   </style>
   </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">

      <div><img id="imglogo" src="img/logo-lr.png" class="center-block img-responsive"></div>
       <div id="forms">
        <div id="error" class="" role="alert"></div>
        Username/Email
        <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="" required autofocus>
        Password
        <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="" required><br>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="mybtn"><span 
 id="login"></span></button>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login").html("Login");

$("#mybtn").click(function(){
    login();
});

function login(){
var user=$("#user").val();
var pass=$("#pass").val();
var url = "somesite@com?login.php";
if($.trim(user).length>0 & $.trim(pass).length>0)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {user:user,pass:pass},
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
          $("#login").html('Logging in...');
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data[0] == 3)
            {   
                window.location.replace("dashboard.html");
            }
            else if(data[0] == 1)
            {
                $("#error").attr('class', 'alert alert-warning');
                $('#error').html("Expired account");
            }
            else if(data[0] == 4)
            {
                $("#error").attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
                $('#error').html("Account doesnt exist!");
            }
            else if(data[0] == 2)
            {
                $("#error").attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
                $('#error').html("Wrong Password!");
            }
            $("#login").html("Login");

        }, error: function(data){
        }
    });
      }return false;
 }
 });
```

Config.xml

```
            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <widget id="com.leuteriorealty.roxanne" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
            <name>leuteriorealty</name>
            <description>
                Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
            </description>
            <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
                PhoneGap Team
            </author>
            <content src="index.html" />
            <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
            <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
            <platform name="android">
                <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
                <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
                <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
            </platform>
            <platform name="ios">
                <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
                <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
                <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
                <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
                <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
                <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
                <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
                <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
                <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
                <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
                <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
                <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
                <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
                <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
                <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
                <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
                <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
                <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
                <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
                <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
                <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
                <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
                <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
                <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
                <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
                <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
            </platform>
            <platform name="wp8">
                <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
                <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
                <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
            </platform>
            <platform name="windows">
                <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
                <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
                <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
                <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
                <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
                <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
                <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
                <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
                <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
                <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
                <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
                <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
                <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
                <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
                <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
            </platform>
            <allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> 
            <allow-intent href="https://*/*" /> 
            <allow-intent href="tel:*" /> 
            <allow-intent href="sms:*" /> 
            <allow-intent href="mailto:*" /> 
            <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
            <platform name="android">
                <access origin="*" />
                <allow-intent href="market:*" />
                <allow-intent href="*" />
                <allow-navigation href="*" />
            </platform>
            <platform name="ios">
                <access origin="*" />
                <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
                <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
            </platform>
            <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="~1.1.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.1.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~1.2.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.2" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="~2.0.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" spec="~1.2.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" spec="~1.0.2" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.2.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.1.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.1.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="~1.0.3" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.3.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~2.2.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.2.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.1" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.2" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="~2.1.0" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.4-dev" />
        </widget>
```

Comment: If you have a problem with your JavaScript you should rather share that then your HTML

Comment: Sorry sir @chade_. I edited my code.

Comment: This `somesite@com?login.php` does not look like a valid URL.

Comment: Just dont mind it sir, it's my web service. The problem is on the device (Phonegap Developer app). It's working on the browser but not on the device.